# Low framerate on android using immediateLayer (and weird playn log message)

Tags: playn

I am trying to get my game running smoothly on android using PlayN, everything works as expected but I have a verry low framerate.
I think i might be doing it the wrong way so it'd be great if someone could give me some help :D.

So I'm currently creating an ImmediateLayer and cleaning it and drawing every objet at every frame, images are loaded once using graphics.getImage(...). I get around 10 fps on a HTC Desire (connected in debug mode) while drawing around 100 images. It gets slower as I add objetcs.
What makes me think I am doing something really wrong is that PlayN is spamming the log (I use DDMS to check the log) with these messages.

> X Textures remaining
>
> Y Textures created

It appears around 20 times per second.

So basically i am doing something like this:

```
public void draw(Surface s){
for (Drawable d : toDraw) {
        surface.drawImage(d.getImage(), d.x, d.y, d.w, d.h); }}
```

Where draw is called in the renderer of an immediateLayer.

thank you for your time!

Lucas

**Edit:**
I found a possible answer reading that thread on playn mailing list.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/playn/XJTlBgmfzaQ

especially that message

> > Most of the tiles share the same image, but different parts of it (atteined 
> >     by subImage, which to my knowledge doesn't copy but rather only creates a 
> >     reference to a sub part to the image?). Would different sub parts cause a 
> >     texture change?
>
> Sub-images will share the same texture, but you have to be sure to 
>   render all the images that share the same texture together. If you 
>   have a bunch of sub images from image A and a bunch from image B and 
>   you render A, B, A, B, A, B, A, B, you are getting same performance as
>   if you rendered eight different images. You need to render A, A, A, A,
>   B, B, B, B.

It seems I am in a worst case scenario.

I have many different textures (say 50), They're all part of a different image and all rendered randomly. I may end up with something close to N texture switch where N is the number of objet i render.

I'll update this when i get something to work :).

**Edit 2:**

I am now rendering 100 objet pointing to the same Image (so no texture swap?). I still get  about 10 fps on android and the debug log is still saying in each frame:

1 textures remain
2 textures created

I feel like i'm missing something important... help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper testing I found that :

1) The htc desire cannot be expected to get 60 fps drawing hundreds of objects even sharing the same image.

2) imageLayer attached to a group layer seems to provide better performance on android

**3) Calling surface.clear() at the beginning of the renderer callback (using immediate layer) greatly improved the performance of the draw and removed the "textures created" debug log.**

4) Finally sorting the object by texture and reducing the number of texture swap (drawing A A A A B B B istead of A B A B A B) gave me better results.

The app is now runnig at 30 fps on the desire and 60 fps on a galaxy S2 drawing around 500 object on screen.